# Why i can not attach files to Event list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, events

I have added an Event list to my SharePoint modern site home page

[image: User's image]

when the user clicks on "Add event" >> the user will not be able to attach a file:-

[image: User's image]

although i have defined to allow Attachments inside my list setting as follow:-

[image: User's image]

any advice? how i can allow users to attach files to my events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a default behavior that attachments cannot be added in the modern Events web part and not caused by some settings are disabled.

Currently, you only could add attachments into classic Events list. Then attachments will show in the modern Events web part.

Comment: thanks for the info and reply